# Auto LTR-RTL Text Direction in wordpress post!

Tags: css, add-editor-style

How can make wordpress auto **direction** to language detected and switch it automatically
**Example**: when i use facebook app or website i usually use it in English language LTR **but** when I write something like Arabic it’s automatically switch text direction to RTL
How can i do this!
I hope to understand me
**Thanks** guys

[image: from my website]
Picture from my website with issue